# Add header to Non-XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Can I somehow intercept a `Non-XMLHttpRequest` (e.g. JavaScript) for adding a header?

Comment: The answer is going to be most likely "no"

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to add a Security-Token. Src of an image is filled in by a Knockout-Binding and in turn calls a protected API.

Comment: FYI: This works like a charm as long as I use HTTP Basic Authentication (the browser adds the header and the credentials as soon as available). However, I want to switch to OAuth...